# LEFT Outer join with conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I’ve got (I think) quite simple problem with SQL.
I’ve got two tables:
Posts(id, body, user_id), and Reports(id, user_id, post_id).

I’d like to display all posts for given user, which he didn’t mark as reported.

I build query something like this:

```
Select * FROM posts LEFT OUTER JOIN 
reports ON reports.post_id = posts.id WHERE reports.id IS NULL
```

However, it takes all reports, not only that added by my user. Of course adding `Where reports.id IS NULL AND reports.user_id = 123` won’t work… Is there any solution for that, or should I do sub query?

BTW: I don’t think that this can make any difference, but I’m running postgres 9.x

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `reports.user_id = 123` to the *join condition*, and not the where clause. This will join only on `reports` rows with `user_id = 123` and eliminate only those matches:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
LEFT OUTER JOIN reports ON reports.post_id = posts.id
    AND reports.user_id = 123
WHERE reports.id IS NULL
```

Alternatively, use a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM reports 
    WHERE reports.post_id = posts.id
    AND reports.user_id = 123
)
```

Comment: great, didn’t know that I can add conditions to ON. Works, thanks!